# Rotational symmetry $\leftrightarrow$ isotropy, dilation symmetry $\leftrightarrow$ ________?

Tags: symmetry, conformal-field-theory, scale-invariance

Symmetries correspond to specific properties of the space in question.

- translation symmetry $\leftrightarrow$ homogeneity,
- rotational symmetry $\leftrightarrow$ isotropy

What property is related to invariance under dilatations?

Answer (score 3):

It's

- dilatation symmetry $\leftrightarrow$ scale invariant.

Comment: The space expansion does not make the universe scale invariant. I think the question is unclear and so is your answer.